# При отключенном javascript не выводить результат json_encode на странице

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, json-encode

Здравствуйте!

С помощью ajax я выполняю определенный код. Изучив некоторые материалы, для того чтобы использовать ответ от сервера в виде массива и передавать его на стороне клиента, необходимо использовать json_encode, а затем распарсить и выводить нужный результат в нужное место. Что я и сделал.

Пример произвольного кода PHP:

```
products($category); 
exit(json_encode(array('id' => '25', 'price' => '5000')));
```

JS:

```
success: function(res){ 
   var result = $.parseJSON(res);
   $("#uuu").html(result.id);
   $("#uuu2").html(result.price);
 }
```

Выполняется функция products(), затем приходит какой-то результат в `json_encode` и затем в `success` вывожу результат. Проблема в том, что когда отключен javascript у пользователя, на странице выводится вместо вывода информации следующее:`{"id":"25","price":"5000"}` Т.е. шаблон сайта вообще не подгружается, а лишь белый экран и эта надпись. Я понимаю, что происходит это скорее всего из-за `exit`.

Если `exit` убрать, и выполнить ajax, выходит ошибка: *SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data*

Как-то можно сделать так, чтобы при отключенном js все работало также, но только получается с перезагрузкой страницы и на php.

Comment: Как ты собрался отправлять ajax при отключенном js?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский никак, будет работать на php. Поэтому на отключенном js выводится `{"id":"25","price":"5000"}`

Comment: ну значит определяй, пришел к тебе в PHP запрос ajax или нет... и от нужной опции отдавай json или массив с данными ..... типа такого `if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
{......`

Comment: Имхо, для API и json нужно иметь один url, а для html - другой (или хотя  бы разделять их параметрами).

Comment: @br3t Не особо понял Вас. Напишите, пожалуйста, подробнее)

Comment: Ну вот у вас одна страница может как вывести что-то нормальное (при включенном js), либо кусок json (при выключенном). Я не совсем понимаю, как вы этого добились, но как будто у вас один и тот же url отвечает и за формирование  страницы,  и за  формирование json для подгрузки его ajaxом на эту же страницу. Либо я вас неправильно понял.

Comment: @br3t По клику на определенную кнопку, выполняется на этой странице ajax. Всю страницу в любом случае изначально формирует php, а далее уже какие-то асинхронные фишки на этой же странице, например, по клику на кнопку, взять id товара и вытащить по нему какую-либо информацию и отобразить ее в div. Или, например, добавление товара в корзину, при ajax в url указывается обработчик на другую страницу (MVC структура), а когда будет отключен js, обработчик будет таким же, как указан в url ajax, но будет произведен редирект....продолжение в след. сообщении.

Comment: т.е. редирект вернет обратно на эту же страницу, но при перезагрузке страницы обратится к обработчику незаметно для пользователя. Я думаю Вы поняли. Ну а проверяю я пришел ajax или нет, как показано в примере выше. Если не ajax то редирект у меня включен, а если ajax то редирект не выполняется, а выполняется json:) За формирование страницы совсем другой url отвечает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо Алексею Шиманскому за его совет.

Определяем, что к нам пришло в PHP запросе, ajax или нет. Затем от нужной опции отдаём json или массив с данными.

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    exit(json_encode(array('id' => '25', 'price' => '5000')));
}else{
    ...
}
```